# Histogram with fraction in qplot / ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]So far I have missed a histogram function with a fraction on the y-axis. Like this:

```
require(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)
idealD <- diamonds[diamonds[,"cut"]=="Ideal",]

fracHist <- function(x){
  frac <- (hist(x,plot=F)$counts) / (sum(hist(x,plot=F)$counts))
  barplot(frac)
}

### call
fracHist(idealD$carat)
```

It ain't pretty but basically should explain what I want: bar heights should add up to one. Plus the breaks should be labelling the x-axis. I'd love to create the same with `ggplot2` `but can't figure out how to get around plotting the frequencies of`frac`instead of plotting`frac`itself`.

```
all I get with `ggplot` is density...

m <- ggplot(idealD, aes(x=carat)) 
m + geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..)) + geom_density()
```

Comment: Sadly, your code isn't reproducible.  Please edit the code such that `idealD` produces a valid `data.frame`, and then also show exactly how you call `fracHist`.

Comment: Thx, Andrie for giving my question a second chance. I put the code in a separate file ran `rm(list=ls())` and tested it. Now it should work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is to use `stat_bin` and map the aesthetic `y=..count../sum(..count..)`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(idealD, aes(x=carat)) + stat_bin(aes(y=..count../sum(..count..)))
```

From a quick scan of `?hist` I couldn't find how the values are binned in `hist`.  This means the graphs won't be identical unless you fiddle with the `binwidth` argument of `stat_bin`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The trick works with geom_histogram histogram as well.

```
require(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)
idealD <- diamonds[diamonds[,"cut"]=="Ideal",]

ggplot(idealD, aes(x=carat))  +   geom_histogram(aes(y=..count../sum(..count..)))
```

[image]